# Economic theory journals for a refinement theorem about utility function representation

Tags: mathematical-economics, utility

I would like to ask which are the (mathematical) economics journals that publish papers about economic theory and that focus mainly on the *mathematical aspects* of it. Let me be more precise. If I have a refinement of a representation theorem for preference relation axiomatization, which journals are most suitable to get the paper accepted?

Of course, I mean a *significant generalization* of the theorem and, of course, I am not thinking about Econometrica or Journal of Economic Theory since I understand my question is about a refinement of a theorem, and not a completely original economic issue. Nevertheless, I think my generalization fills an important gap in the subject and I would like to ask for a list of economics journals (maybe listed by ranking of importance) that may be the right target for my result. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For theory you have in order of *prestige*... (I know subjective)

- [Journal of Economic Theory](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-economic-theory)
- [Theoretical Economics](https://econtheory.org/)
- [AEJ-Micro](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/mic) (only micro)
- [Mathematics of Operations Research](https://pubsonline.informs.org/journal/moor) (OR related)
- [Games and economic behaviour](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/games-and-economic-behavior) (only game theory)
- [Economic theory](https://www.springer.com/journal/199/)
- [Journal of Mathematical Economics](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-mathematical-economics)
- [Social choice and welfare](https://www.springer.com/journal/355) (only social choice)
- [Theory and Decision](https://www.springer.com/journal/11238)
- [Mathematical social sciences](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/mathematical-social-sciences)
- $\ldots$

There are of course other journals that publish theory, like:

- International journal of Game theory
- Economic Inquiry
- Economics Theory Bulletin

Feel free to add to the list.

Comment: Thank you very much! In any case, which do you consider more suitable for "hardcore" decision theory? I mean theorems about axiomatization and representation of preference relations by a utility function? And if the theorem is only a refinement of an old one (Debreu 1964, say), how much prestige can one guess it to be? (I know it's not easy to tell, but just to have a rough intuition)

Comment: Journal of math econ or Mathematcal social sciences? [Theory and decision](https://www.springer.com/journal/11238) (not mentioned in my answer) might also be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks again! Let me wait if other answers come, otherwise I'll accept yours!

Comment: These are the journals theorist strive to publish in (apart from the Top 5 obviously), but I might add Mathematics of Operations Research if it is particularly technical as well.

Comment: @Walrasian Auctioneer, I agree they are the best theory journals, but as tdm wrote above, I see quite a big difference in prestige between even Econ Theory and Mathematical Social Sciences... even if sometimes I saw papers in Econ Theory that deserved JET and others that deserved no more than Theory and Decisions... what do you think?...... btw let me add Theory and Decisions

Comment: @tdm, in someone else shoes, would you suggest trying a higher rank journal first, getting a rejection (likely), and eventually try a second-tier, or would you aim to the second straightforward to save time?

Comment: @Porcupine It depends. 1. do you think your paper makes a chance and (more importantly) 2. How much time do you have. If you are willing to wait (and have the money... not all submissions are for free) it's not a bad idea to try something more highly ranked. Even if you get a rejection, the referee reports might be helpful to update your paper. Publishing is to a large extend a large number game: if you have enough papers under circulation you'll be able to publish regularly even if you have a rejection now and then.